# how can I make sure only 1 instance of the function is running at any given time?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am writing a spring-boot application with @Scheduled or Shedlock which runs a function every 10 mins. That function may take varying times depending on the load, 10 min or maybe even 20 mins.

I want to make sure that the @Scheduled or Shedlock doesn't run another instance of that function while the current function is actively running. What's the best way of doing that?

I don't have a database, but I was thinking I can use DynamoDB or Redis Cache. One issue I can see is that if let's say the application crashes in the middle of the job, it will still have the cache entry. Sure, I can add a TTL to the cache entry, but then the app will still have to wait till the TTL expires.

Is there a better way to handle this situation?

Comment: Is a `fixedDelay` of 10 minutes acceptable? (I'm assuming you mean `@Scheduled` not `@Schedule`). That would mean that you would have up to 30 minutes between executions.

Comment: @tgdavies Yes! fixedDelay is something that would work perfectly!  So, if I have a fixedDelay of 10 mins then my next task will only have to wait for 10mins after the finish of task1. I am not sure how, it will take 30 mins between execution?

Comment: If one execution takes 20 minutes, then the start time of the next execution will be 30 minutes after the start time of the previous execution, which may be fine, but is something to be aware of.

Comment: Hi @tgdavies if you can post this as an answer that'd be great.